Soft deleted records are getting fetched from database laravel 10
Soft deleted records are getting fetched from database.
I have added soft delete to Category model. 'deleted_at' column is being set when I soft delete a record. But, when I fetch the result from database using
Category::latest('id')->paginate(20)

it is returning deleted records as well.
My Category model
class Category extends Model
{
    use  SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'description',
        'is_active',
        'image',
    ];
}

Check query using telescope and it run this.
select * from `categories` order by `id` desc limit 20 offset 0

But it should run
select * from `categories` where `deleted_at` is null order by `id` desc limit 20 offset 0


Installed laravel 10 previous day. My other project soft delete is working fine

are you using some global scope?

I'm find my solution. I was used an trait that not mention in model here. on that trait constructor, i didn't call  parent::__construct(). that was the problem. now i'm called  parent::__construct(); this in trait construct , and it worked.

I'm find my solution.
I was used an trait that not mention in model here. on that trait constructor, i didn't call parent::__construct(). that was the problem. now i'm called parent::__construct();  in trait construct , and it worked.
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}


You should create a migration as well:
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropSoftDeletes();
        });
    }
};

With above, following code will not show deleted categories:
Category::latest('id')->paginate(20)

by doing above if its not working, then we have only choice left by using following code:
Category::whereNull('deleted_at')->latest('id')->paginate(20);


if you’re seeing soft deleted records when using
Category::latest('id')->paginate(20),

it’s likely because you need to explicitly tell Eloquent to only fetch non-deleted records. By default, latest() and paginate() do not exclude soft deleted records. like below  -
Category::whereNull('deleted_at')->latest('id')->paginate(20);


latest() and paginate()  work with soft delete

To get the most recent non-deleted records, you simply use latest() and paginate() without any additional methods.
